# Joomla DB Object with where and Now()

Tags: database, select, joomla

can someone help me with this? I want to query some data for my joomla 2.5
template from the db.

The known mysql syntax

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `jos_fieldsattach_values` WHERE value > NOW() and value < NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY");
```

works as expexted but if I try to write this in the joomla db syntax the query fails

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$db->setQuery($query);

$query
    ->select(array('*'))
    ->from('#__fieldsattach_values');           
    ->where('WHERE value > NOW() and value < NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY'); 

$result = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($result);
```

It seems somethings wrong with the where clause ?

Thankful for you answers,

tony

Comment: firs you can jsut do select('*')also
Why are you repeating WHERE inside the WHERE? THat's going to generate some strange looking syntax like WHERE WHERE and also I'd use the built in time stamp function so you have multidb support.
You can always see your query in the debugger or you can put in echo $query->dump(); anywhere to get the query as it is at a particular point. Also try to use $db->quote() and $db->quoteName() to make sure you are using the right quotes.

Comment: `$db->setQuery($query);` also needs to come after the actual query

Comment: The above comments hit most of the issues. I just want to add that you can always add `echo $query` to your script to see the actual query that is being developed. Compare that to your first query that works and the errors should be obvious (like the double `WHERE`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. When you develop anything with Joomla you should turn on FULL Error reporting (**Configuration/Server/Error Reporting/Development**) then set system debugging (**Configuration/System/Debug System/Yes**). It will show all errors, those from system and those from php/mysql. But remember make sure website is not visible for other users to. Now, your code should look more like this:

```php
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select("*")->from('#__fieldsattach_values')->where('value > NOW() AND value < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)'); 
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($result);
```